# How to call a MFC Regular DLL in Dart or Flutter?

Tags: c++, dart, dll, mfc, flutter-windows

How could I call a MFC Regular DLL in Dart/Flutter?

I successfully called a pure (No MFC) C++ DLL.
But when I pasted the same code into a new-created MFC regular DLL project, DART RUN gave me:

> `Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol 'hello_world': error code 127 ...`

Below is my own code:

- lib_mfc\pch.h:

  ```cpp
  extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void hello_world();
  ```
- lib_mfc\pch.cpp

  ```cpp
  void hello_world()
  {
      printf("[From C++:] Hello World\n");
  }
  ```
- bin\ffi_sample.dart **// it works well for a non-mfc dll**

  ```dart
  final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open(libraryPath);
  final ffi.Pointer<T> Function<T extends ffi.NativeType>(String symbolName) _lookup = dylib.lookup;
  late final _hello_worldPtr = _lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function()>>('hello_world');
  late final _hello_world = _hello_worldPtr.asFunction<void Function()>();
  _hello_world();
  ```

Comment: You are either failing to load the library, or the library's exports aren't called what you think they are. Try `dumpbin /EXPORTS <module>` to see what the exported symbols are really called.

Comment: Thanks. you are right. I wrote the MFC DLL incorrectly. I re-write the DLL, following the MFC DLL guide. Now it works.